# Advantage of installing redis from source rather than redis-server package

Tags: php, laravel-5, redis

To summarize, I am building a laravel application which is likely to have a heavy database usage. I wanted to use caching for my database resultsets wherever possible and was considering using redis as cache provider. I am completely new to redis, i have been using mysql query caching or file caching as caches prior to this project.

I was reading about setting up redis and came across two options - either compile from source code (which will install latest stable version 4.0) or use redis-server package (which installs 3.0 version). However i am not completely sure which way to go.

Can anyone please guide me what is the best and what additional features does 4.0 give me over 3.0 which i will need from my laravel application perspective. My initial bias is towards using apt install given it simplicity to execute and reliability as it is an official package.  But i am wondering if installing an old version will deprive me of any major improvements in the 4.0 release of redis.

To conclude, i am not sure this belongs to a programming question category, but i am looking for answers from a programmer's perspective hence decided to post it here.

Comment: So... MySQL saves working data to RAM. Redis saves all data to RAM. MySQL requires a connection. Redis requires a connection. MySQL is a server. Redis is a server. MySQL has *better* memory management than Redis. Are you 100% sure that duplicating the data you work with (because you will save it to Redis) is going to do.. anything for you? You'll have to write a layer that deals with caching, with its own logic (no matter how trivial) because you *assumed* that adding Redis to avoid MySQL querying is going to be faster. Rethink.

Comment: This is very debatable. May be true when the queries are simple and database resides on the same machine. I have seen around 10x faster speeds with even simple file caching when queries involve multiple joins or resultsets are big. Query caching was good, but MySQL are stopping that feature soon.

Comment: It's not debatable at all. Literally. MySQL is made to be *super* slow by default, you need to increase `innodb_buffer_pool_size` so it can take advantage of all that nice RAM. You can materialize your result-set so you don't re-calculate the same thing over and over again. Or, you can just use Redis because you want to. There's no need to justify your decision, and there's no need to come up with bogus argument to strengthen it. I've no clue why you mention query cache whatsoever. Before you optimize anything, add numbers first. "Heavy" database usage means.. nothing.

Comment: From your profile, I am sure you are having good enough knowledge to make this statement. I will give your advise a go, will try to optimize the database instead of using redis. Can you point me to any good article which details about improving mysql database performance and data fetching speed?

Comment: I'll try to be objective and as helpful as I can so you can go the right way - first off, ignore the reputation on this site, it's not always correct reflection of one's ability. Redis and MySQL *are* used in conjunction but in specific workloads. First thing you need to determine is what types of queries you're going to do and how often. *How often* is the crucial part. My honest advice would be to develop your site first, then optimize it. If you optimize first - you'll never be done. Once you start getting traffic and experience slowness - then you optimize.

Comment: As for articles about optimizing MySQL - do a simple thing first - allow MySQL to eat up as much RAM as possible, while still leaving some for PHP and operating system. You do that via `innodb_buffer_pool_size_variable`. Percona's website is full of excellent articles so refer to that. Important thing to do is to create the appropriate data model - this is a wide topic, that's something you've to do on your own and fix as you go (if you make a mistake).